# Java For each loop object assignment is not working

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

```
public class A{

    int val;    
    public A(int val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(val);

    }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        A[] aList = new A[10];
        int temp =1;

        for(A a : aList){
            a = new A(temp++);          
        }

        for(A a : aList){
            a.print();;         
        }

    }


}
```

Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at A.main(A.java:28)
aList address space Class A objects are stored but again iterate unable to get stored objects, where are the objects stored ?

Answer (score 14):

`a` is a local variable of the for loop, so assigning to it doesn't affect the elements of the aList array.

You should use a regular for loop to initialize the array :

```
    for(int i = 0; i < aList.length; i++){
        aList[i] = new A(temp++);          
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how an enhanced for works. Use a standard for loop instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < aList.length; i++){
   aList[i] = new A(temp++);          
}
```

The enhanced for uses an Iterator to loop through every element of the array. And since your array only contains null values, you're getting a NullPointerException.